# Find the closest value in each group in a matrix column

Tags: matlab

This is another operation based on the same matrix data, as I talked about in the previous question. I have a matrix as below.

```
a = [1.05 2.1 3.4 1; 1.06 2.2 3.6 1; 2.04 2.3 3.8 2; 2.15 2.2 4.0 2; 1.37 2.3 3.7 1;3.12 2.1 4.1 3;3.02 2.2 4.2 3;3.42 2.3 4.5 3;3.24 2.4 4.8 3]

a =

1.0500    2.1000    3.4000    1.0000
1.0600    2.2000    3.6000    1.0000
2.0400    2.3000    3.8000    2.0000
2.1500    2.2000    4.0000    2.0000
1.3700    2.3000    3.7000    1.0000
3.1200    2.1000    4.1000    3.0000
3.0200    2.2000    4.2000    3.0000
3.4200    2.3000    4.5000    3.0000
3.2400    2.4000    4.8000    3.0000
```

a(:,4) is group numbers. Based on group numbers, I split the matrix data into 3 groups: 1, 2 and 3.

I would like to find the index of value closest to 2.2 in a(:,2) **in each group**. From the data you can see, there is a 2.2 in row 2 belong to group 1, a 2.2 in row 4 belong to group 2, and a 2.2 in row 7 belong to group 3.

My code is shown as below:

```
[minValue,closestIndex] = splitapply(@(x)min(abs(2.2-x)), a(:,2), findgroups(a(:,4)))
```

The outcome is:

```
minValue =

 0
 0
 0
```

This is consistent as we can find from the data.

```
closestIndex =

 2
 2
 2
```

This is supposed to be the indexes of three 2.2 in the matrix, which should be 2, 4 and 7. But the outcome is 2, 2 and 2.

What is wrong with my code?

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how this function works. It split your initial setup:

```
a =

1.0500    2.1000    3.4000    1.0000
1.0600    2.2000    3.6000    1.0000
2.0400    2.3000    3.8000    2.0000
2.1500    2.2000    4.0000    2.0000
1.3700    2.3000    3.7000    1.0000
3.1200    2.1000    4.1000    3.0000
3.0200    2.2000    4.2000    3.0000
3.4200    2.3000    4.5000    3.0000
3.2400    2.4000    4.8000    3.0000
```

to

```
x1=
1.0500    2.1000    3.4000    1.0000
1.0600    2.2000    3.6000    1.0000 (index = 2)
1.3700    2.3000    3.7000    1.0000
x2=
2.0400    2.3000    3.8000    2.0000
2.1500    2.2000    4.0000    2.0000 (index = 2)
x3=
3.1200    2.1000    4.1000    3.0000
3.0200    2.2000    4.2000    3.0000 (index = 2)
3.4200    2.3000    4.5000    3.0000
3.2400    2.4000    4.8000    3.0000
```

The indexes are examined separately so indeed - 2,2,2 is correct answer for this query. According to the documentation "The splitapply function calls func once per group" so there is not simple possibility to obtain indexes from initial matrix directly. Maybe you can workaround it by adding another column like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and store the number from it or something in this way but it is not so elegant and would require quite complicated `func`.